# Spring .properties file in located in classpath

Tags: spring-mvc, properties, classpath

If I do

```
<value>classpath:site/properties/default/placeholder.properties</value>
```

What does the `classpath:` actually mean?  Does that mean my properties file needs to be in a place that won't be easily updateable?  I would like a .properties file to be in a location where a webmaster can change settings on the fly if needed.  Can you still do that with a .properties file located in the classpath:?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`classpath:` points to files located in the `classes` directory. In other words, your `placeholder.properties` is located in `<classes-dir>/site/properties/default` directory. I don't think the webmaster is allowed to change the settings on the fly once you deployed the project, I mean, you could change it, but it probably won't take effect at all.

Comment: Is there anyway to have a file you can change on the fly?

Comment: if you need the properties to be easily updated, why not place the key-pair values in database table?

Comment: Database is a correct way to do it, but doing it in a database is not in scope here.